# VoIP call interruption with my internet

Tags: voip

I Have 2 D link 2025u Dsl Routers with 6Mbps Download speed and 0.60 mbps upload speed and i have total 10 user to call over internet via skype and voip connect software, We facing problem with call disconnected, voice not clear and interruption with calling Please suggest me to how to resolve same on caller not calling continuously My total bandwidth is 16mbps download and 2mbps upload.

Thank You

Comment: You state that you have 6 Mbps download and 0.60 Mbps upload in one place, and 16 Mbps download and 2 Mbps upload in another. Which is it? With Skype, are you making voice-only calls, or are you also doing video?

Comment: no our user make calls only via skype and voip software